# how can my app send a push notification when my app is on the fg?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, push-notification

I have a swift app.

I get a GCM push notification from my server.

In IOS I understand the OS takes care of showing the notification when my app is in the bg.

How can I show a push message (notification) when my app is on fg and I'm the one responsible fro showing the notification?

Should I use local-push (as contrast to remote-push) ?

What is the code to show the push as seen when the app is in the bg?

I know this code handles showing a push to the user

but it's not notification, it's just opens an alert

```
func application( application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
        // This works only if the app started the GCM service
        GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
        // Handle the received message
        // Invoke the completion handler passing the appropriate UIBackgroundFetchResult value
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
            userInfo: userInfo)
        handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the notification (in userInfo) but it will not show if the app is in foreground. What you can do is either fire a local notification or use UIAlertView when app is in foreground.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;  //For resetting the badge number to zero.           


    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)  //For checking if app is in foreground.        
    {                

       UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Notification received:" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Received notification while app was in foreground:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alertView show];          
  }    
}
```

Comment: do you have a swift example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle notifications when the app is in the foreground you might use custom banners like this one https://github.com/LeoNatan/LNNotificationsUI.
The code should appear like that:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
    {                
        LNNotification* notification = [LNNotification notificationWithMessage:@"Notification Message"];

        [[LNNotificationCenter defaultCenter] presentNotification:notification forApplicationIdentifier:@"app_identifier"];
    }
}
```